# How do I get the count based on the condition in 2 columns

Tags: reporting-services

Here is the output from my SSRS report. What I would like to do is calculate the %Compliance based on
Test_result (only when there is an actually result, ie 25, 99, 97.6) and Meds (only when there is an actually result, ie Lipitor)
divided by the total number of ID (in this case 13)

or %Compliance = [(Test_result, Meds) / Total ID]*100
   %Compliance = (3 / 13)*100

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Ass**u**me**ing that the **Test_result** will have **No_LDL** if there is no result and **Meds** = **No_Meds** when there are no meds, you could do a **SUM** with an **IIF** that check the criteria:

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!Test_result.Value <> 'NO_LDL_RESULT' 
     AND FIELDS!Meds.Value <> 'NO_MEDS_PRESCRIBED' 
     AND ISNUMERIC(FIELDS!Test_result.Value), 
   CDEC(FIELDS!Test_result.Value), 
   0)
 /
COUNTROWS()
```

You can set the **FORMAT property** to P2 to format it as a percentage with two decimal places (instead of using a Format **function**).